# Is SSH using TLS?

Tags: tls, openssl, ssh

I have an odd case where a vulnerability scan is reporting that sshd is vulnerable because of TLS.  I didn't think SSH used TLS, so can someone help me explain why "openssl s_client -connect hostname:22 -tls1" shows SSH is accepting TLS connections?

For example:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myhost:22 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000004)
140300455982912:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 104 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1598564402
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The more I look at it, the more it looks like the -tls1 flag causes additional output, but it doesn't look like the connection is actually established.  If I remove the -tls1 flag, nothing is reported... whereas, if I specify the same command without the flag and point it to a webserver, I get a lot more TLS connection information indicating a successful connection.

Comment: It's not the `-tls1` flag. `s_client` was intended to be a test/debug tool and by default produces a lot of data about the session negotiation _unless_ you use `-quiet`. In the case you posted, if you know how to read it, this data clearly indicates the connection (handshake) failed, even without having the error message explicitly saying so. For a successful connection, except for the server cert or chain, you don't actually get many _more_ items of data, but many of them are _larger_, some of them much larger, making the total larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SSH does not use TLS. It uses [its own protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) that provides encryption.

Note your second line of output:

```
140300455982912:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332
```

That looks like a fatal error, so any additional output is probably debug-related.

Comment: Also `New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)` indicates that the TLS negotiation failed.